How does a delta for an fx option take into account translation risk?
Say I buy a FX option on DOM/FOR and the premium is received in, say, FOR, and my base currency is DOM.
What is the delta of this option?
Is it $f'(s)$ where $f$is the pricing formula and $s$ is the spot rate, or is it the derivative of $f(s)/s$, i.e. the value of the fx option in domestic currency?

Just to make it more exciting, what market risks do you have if your accounting is in GBP, and you trade a non-delivery EUR/RUB option that will be cash settled in USD?

A concrete example will help to understand, with real numbers.
But, you need to take the derivative of what you ultimately care about.
So if $f(s)$ is the PV of the book (the thing you look at), then $f'(s)$ is more correct.
Otherwise, when you hedge, you zero the sensitivity of the "wrong" thing.
